# Why is the maximum adiabatic temperature found for an equivalence ratio a bit higher than 1?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, combustion, fuel

Why does the peak adiabatic temperature usually happen for an equivalence ratio a bit higher than 1? I think it had something to do with the probability of each fuel molecule finding a corresponding oxidizer, and the fact that the molecular weight of the fuel is generally higher than that of the oxidizer.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but is it because nitrogen in the air is inert, and you have to "waste" a bit of the heat from combustion to heat it up?  It's a small effect, relative to the heat of combustion, so my guess is the the max temperature would be ever-so-slightly to the carbon-rich side of the equivalence ratio.

Comment: > [...] $\phi = 1.1$ was chosen because the flame temperature for many fuel peaks not at the stoichiometric value but between $\phi = 1.0$ and $\phi = 1.1$ owing to lower mean specific heats of the richer products. The maximum temperature for acetylene-air peaks, for example, at a value of $\phi = 1.3$.$^{[1]}$ ## References 1. [Irwin Glassman, Richard A. Yetter, *Combustion*, 4th ed; Academic Press: New York, 2008](https://www.elsevier.com/books/combustion/glassman/978-0-12-088573-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the answer in this [2011 paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20121229075337/http://lcg.princeton.edu:80/publications/conference-publications/law-on-the-off-stoichiometric-peaking-of-adiabatic-flame-temperature.aspx), here is a quote from the abstract:

> The characteristic rich shifting of the maximum adiabatic flame temperature from the stoichiometric value for
>   hydrocarbon/air mixtures is demonstrated to be caused by product dissociation and hence reduced amount of heat release.
>   Since the extent of dissociation is greater on the lean side as a result of the stoichiometry of dissociated products, the peaking
>   occurs on the rich side.